# How do I output the time in postgres sql

Tags: postgresql, date, psql

I know about `\echo` but that just seems to output the rest of the line literally, i want something like \echo date

Comment: `select current_date;`

Comment: thx thats does indeed work

Comment: Please take a look to the documentation to learn differences between [current_date](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) and other function that gives also the current date/time --> [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on the comment

```
select current_time
```

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The only example in pg docs is actually the answer to this...

\echo `date`

Answer (score 0):

And if you want both the date and the time (almost always) use:

`select now();`